# Wordpress Illegal Offset error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have no knowledge regarding wordpress. Can anyone please solve my error?

```
<?php

/** Add the quotelist button/link to the single product page based on the selction of the position **/
global $dvin_wcql_settings,$dvin_wcql_link_positions;
//apply the filter
$dvin_wcql_link_positions = apply_filters( 'dvin_wcql_custom_link_positions' , $dvin_wcql_link_positions );
/** determine the position, if not shortcode and replace Add to Cart Button**/
if($dvin_wcql_link_positions[$dvin_wcql_settings['link_position']]['hook_name'] == "woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button"){
    add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','dvin_makeitpurchaseable');
    add_action($dvin_wcql_link_positions[$dvin_wcql_settings['link_position']]['hook_name'], 'dvin_remove_addtocart_button',1);
    add_action($dvin_wcql_link_positions[$dvin_wcql_settings['link_position']]['hook_name'], 'dvin_addquotelist_button',2);
}else if($dvin_wcql_link_positions[$dvin_wcql_settings['link_position']]['hook_name'] != "useshortcode") {
        add_action($dvin_wcql_link_positions[$dvin_wcql_settings['link_position']]['hook_name'], 'dvin_remove_addtocart_button',40);
    add_action($dvin_wcql_link_positions[$dvin_wcql_settings['link_position']]['hook_name'], 'dvin_addquotelist_button',$dvin_wcql_link_positions[$dvin_wcql_settings['link_position']]['priority']);
}
?>
```

Error in error_log is as follows:
Illegal string offset 'link_position'

Comment: var_dump($dvin_wcql_settings); and check is there a link_position key

Comment: it is showing this on every page of mine website string(1) "1" @FastSnail

Comment: you need  to check whether u r getting the value of that array or not ?